# Blacklisting characters in a controlP5 textField

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

In the controlP5 library, I need to prohibit certain characters from being entered into a `textField`.

I found a piece of code where you indicate what to prohibit, but I don’t know how to enforce the conditions (possibly by emulating the erase button?).

This is what I'd like to whitelist:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ControlP5 provides built-in whitelist filters for numbers: integers (0-9) and floats (which is integers and `.`):

`textField.setInputFilter(ControlP5.INTEGER);`

`textField.setInputFilter(ControlP5.FLOAT);`

Looking at your screenshot, it seems you want to whitelist `,` too. Custom filters are not possible, even when `extending` the `Textfield` class due to how the class is setup (the critical members are `protected` or `private`).

So that leaves you with this indirect option to additionally whitelist `,`:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKey() == ',') {
        textField.setText(textField.getText() + ',');
    }
}
```

`,` is whitelisted by appending it to the textfield's current text when Processing detects the correct key pressed event.

Comment: Good afternoon, the function works strange. When entering a comma after a digit, two commas are typed! How to make a blacklist to prohibit entering different characters?

Comment: @ВадимКузьмин Two commas are typed because you aren't setting a filter first. The filter blacklists all non-numeric characters (including comma). Then, the code in keyPressed() then adds this blacklisted comma to the textField. If you don't add the filter first, then the original comma can be typed as normal, and then the code adds another comma -- this is what you are experiencing.

Comment: Please give me a complete working example of my code, with limited characters per line. I will be very grateful.

Comment: @ВадимКузьмин are you calling `textField.setInputFilter(ControlP5.INTEGER);` on your textfield in setup()?

Comment: The formatting of your comment is very messed up for me (possibly due to russian characters). Nonetheless, I can't see any call to setInputFilter().

Comment: Ok, now call X10.setInputFilter(ControlP5.INTEGER);

Comment: Okay, got it.
Now where to insert the character delimiter?  if (X10.getText().lenght() > 5){

Comment: In keyPressed() ?

Comment: @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            if (x10.getText().length() >= 3 ) // limit to 3 characters
                e.consume();  - - - ?????????                                            if (event.getKey() == ',') {
        textField.setText(textField.getText() + ',');
    }                                                                          
        }
    });

Comment: The code works, but there is a problem with character limitation. How will it be correct? See The last foto!!!

Comment: `textField.setText(textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText().length() - 1));`

Comment: It is not at all worth writing in the X10 field. Only with parameter - 0
How to be?

Comment: private void X10KeyPressed (KeyEvent event)
{
    if(X10.getText().length()>=5)
    {
        X10.setText(X10.getText().substring(0, 4));
    }
}

Comment: Mark this question as answered and create another question about that if you need.

Comment: How to mark a question solved, where I don’t know to click?

Comment: Did. Please help with the following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172816/how-to-make-a-number-input-range-from-in-a-textfield