# How to specify a number input range in a controlP5 textField?

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

Specifically, how do I prevent input when the first character is , and 0 in a textField? The controlP5 filter did not work. public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) { int key = e.getKeyCode(); if (key => 5 && key <= 25) e.setKeyChar('' ... //x10.setText ? How to make a number input range from in a textField
How to prevent input by the first character "," and "0" in textField. if (points> = 5 && points <= 25) {example the Controlp5 library did not work. http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/Textfield.InputFilter.html.

Comment: public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            if (key => 5 && key <= 25) 
e.setKeyChar('');
}; 
});    //x10.setText ??????

Comment: If you want to restrict the numbers people can enter to a specific range, how out using a slider or knob instead of a textfield?

Comment: I agree with you, but I cannot put a comma there. 9.6 different options 10.5. So I'm looking for a way to do it in a text box. addSlider already tried in ControlP5.

Comment: How about call getText() and check the contents against a regex expression every time a key is pressed; if it doesn't pass the regex, delete the last character.

Comment: An interesting solution, but what will the code itself look like?

Comment: @ВадимКузьмин Does it need to be a textField ? Wouldn't be easier to use other components such as Numberbox or even a Slider ? (You could easily constrain these to min,max value ranges and specify the precision/number of steps in between values to use)

Comment: Good afternoon, I'll try again addslider, Numberbox and answer option and unsubscribe. The addtextField option was a priority for me, but maybe I'm looping it for us.

Comment: An excellent solution, changed the range from 1-16.8, all conditions are the same for me. Thank you very much, your head works well, for you !!!

Comment: Is there a solution trick? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63291207/how-can-i-remove-a-set-of-two-commas-in-adjacent-text-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is what you want -- put it at the end of `draw()` (rather than `keyPressed()` because `keyPressed()` is called before controlP5 consumes the key event).

However, what you're asking for is problematic. You want to validate the number as the user types in input, and not after the input is fully entered. This leads to a problem: suppose they wish to type in "15"; they first type "1", but this will be rejected because it is not within the correct range (5-25). It would be better to validate input after it is fully entered (when the enter key is pressed for example), or use slider or knob instead.

```
if (keyPressed && textField.isFocus()) {
    float n;
    try {
        n = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().replace(',', '.')); // may throw exception
        if (!(n >= 5 && n <= 25)) {
            throw new NumberFormatException(); // throw to catch below
        }

    } catch (Exception e2) {
        String t;
        if (textField.getText().length() > 1) {
            t = textField.getText().substring(0, textField.getText().length() - 1);
        } else {
            t = "";
        }
        textField.setText(t);
    }
}
```